# Conservation of momentum in an elastic collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

At around **23:00** minutes in [Walter Lewin's Lecture #16 on *Elastic and Inelastic Collisions*](http://youtu.be/ogiY6xt_TRM), he introduced a problem as follow:

A ball with mass $m$ and velocity $v$ encounter Elastic collision with a rigid wall. So the only ball has Kinetic energy before and after the collision, also wall is at rest so its momentum  is $0$. Later he told that after collision momentum of the ball changed by $2mv$, please explain how ball's momentum changed by $2mv$, and if it changed then how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as *unclear* because there is no information content except a link. If you want an answer from us, please *add in details from the video* yourself and don't rely on the link.

Comment: @KyleKanos now see is it ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of Walter Lewin's interesting questions on this course.
The falicy is that the mass of the wall is infinite.

If you give the wall (and the Earth to which it is attached) a mass $M$ and work through the conservation of momentum and conservation of kinetic energy equations you get that the rebound velocity of the mass $m$ is less than $v$ $(=\dfrac{m-M}{m+M}v)$ and the wall has a finite speed $(= \dfrac{2m}{m+M}v)$.

Them assuming that $M \rightarrow \infty$, which in practice is impossible, gives you Professor Lewin's result.

---

**Update**

Look at $\dfrac{m-M}{m+M}v)$ if $M\gg m$.

You get the rebound velocity of mass $m$ is $-v$ and so the change in momentum of mass $m$ is $-mv - (mv) = -2mv$

Comment: but why its momentum changed by $2mv$? please include that too.

Comment: @Ayushakj Look at $\dfrac{m-M}{m+M}v)$ if $M\gg m$.  You get the rebound velocity of mass $m$ is $-v$ and so the change in momentum of mass $m$ is $-mv - (mv) = -2mv$